# any way to reconstruct new dataframe by summarizing different column conditionally in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to reconstruct new dataframe from input data by summarizing and conditioning different columns. I have used `dplyr` utilities to accomplish this but I didn't get my expected output. Essentially, in my input data, I intend to `group_by` subject first then summarize it by its `transfer_time`, then find out whether subject has `ICU` string in `environment` column, and `Intensive` string in `level` column. I figured out the way of doing this by getting two sub dataframe first then merge them by common `subject` column, but merged dataframe is not what I expected.

**reproducible data**

here is the [reproducible data on public gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/3a97bdcb7f6d8bea11a770309c539da6) that taken from original input data

**my current attempt**

```
library(dplyr)

dat = read.csv("mydf.csv", header = TRUE)
    df_1 <- dat %>% group_by(subject) %>% filter(grepl("Intensive", level)) %>% summarise(first_icu=min(transfer_time))
    df_1$first_icu <- ifelse(grepl("0", df_1$first_icu_transfer_time), 1, NA)
    df_2 = dat %>% group_by(subject) %>% summarise(flag = sum(unique(grepl('ICU',environment) & grepl("Intensive", level))))
    final_df <- merge(df_1, df_2, by.x="subject", by.y="subject") %>% write.csv(.,file = "newdf.csv")
```

but above attempt is actually not correct.

**expected output**

here is my accurate expected output dataframe that I manually did it as follow:

> ```
> subject   first_icu_transfer  icu_flag
> subject1  NA  0
> subject2  NA  0
> subject3  154 1
> subject4  NA  0
> subject5  571 1
> subject6  NA  0
> subject7  298 1
> ```

How can I expected output like this from the input dataframe? where was wrong in my code? any idea to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to correct the behavior is by adding `complete` at the end

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
final_df <- merge(df_1, df_2, by.x="subject", by.y="subject")
final_df %>%
       complete(subject = paste('Subject', 1:7), fill = list(flag = 0))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  subject   first_icu  flag
#  <chr>         <int> <dbl>
#1 Subject 1        NA     0
#2 Subject 2        NA     0
#3 Subject 3       154     1
#4 Subject 4        NA     0
#5 Subject 5       571     1
#6 Subject 6        NA     0
#7 Subject 7       298     1
```

---

Or in the `merge`, use `all = TRUE`

```
merge(df_1, df_2, by.x="subject", by.y="subject", all = TRUE)
#   subject first_icu flag
#1 Subject 1        NA    0
#2 Subject 2        NA    0
#3 Subject 3       154    1
#4 Subject 4        NA    0
#5 Subject 5       571    1
#6 Subject 6        NA    0
#7 Subject 7       298    1
```

---

Or if we have to do this in a slightly more compact way

```
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(subject) %>%
   summarise(first_icu = min(transfer_time[str_detect(level, 'Intensive')], na.rm = TRUE), 
   flag = +(sum(str_detect(environment, 'ICU') & str_detect(level, 'Intensive')) > 0)) %>%
   mutate(first_icu = na_if(first_icu, Inf))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$subject), 
 function(x) data.frame(subject = x$subject[1], 
     first_icu = min(x$transfer_time[grepl(x = x$level, 
   'Intensive')], na.rm = TRUE), 
   flag = sum(grepl("ICU", x$environment) & grepl("Intensive", x$level)))))

 out$first_icu[is.infinite(out$first_icu)] <- NA
 out$flag <- +(out$flag > 0)
```

Comment: @beyond_inifinity i added a new approach

Comment: how can I do the same manipulation only using `base` utilities? I am amazed by your solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you are the one contributed most in R related post, big thumbs to your effort.

Comment: I might collect all of your answered post to create cheetsheet. thanks for your contribution

Comment: @beyond_inifinity added one option with base R

Comment: why use `+` in `+(sum(str_detect(environment, 'ICU') & str_detect(level, 'Intensive')) > 0))`, and why `na_if(first_icu, Inf)` ? I want to understand and learn your code. Thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity `v1 <- c(1, 0, 5, 3, 2); v1 > 0` returns logical `as.integer(v1 > 0)`  or `+(v1 > 0)` coerces TRUE/FALSE to 1/0